# Configuring multiple devices in PortAudio: Invalid device error

Tags: portaudio

This query is regarding the Portaudio framework. A little background before I ask the question:I am working on an application in PortAudio to output audio through a multichannel(=8) device. However, the device I am using does not expose itself as a single 8-channel  device but instead shows up in my device-list as 4 stereo devices. On searching for an approach to handle this, I got to know that WinMME in PortAudio supports multiple devices.

Now, I went through the appropriate header file("pa_win_wmme.h") and followed the suggestions present. But I get the 'Invalid device' error (error number -9996) after calling PA_OpenStream(). In the above mentioned header file, they have in fact specified the right parameter(s) to use when configuring multiple devices to avoid this error, but in-spite of following them, I still get the error. 
So I wanted to know if anybody has faced a similar issue and whether I have missed/wrongly configured anything.

I am pasting the required snippets of code below for reference:

```
PaStreamParameters outputParameters;
PaWinMmeStreamInfo wmmeStreamInfo;
PaWinMmeDeviceAndChannelCount wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels;**
...
...
outputParameters.device = paUseHostApiSpecificDeviceSpecification;
outputParameters.channelCount = 8;
outputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32; /* 32 bit floating point processing */
outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

wmmeStreamInfo.size = sizeof(PaWinMmeStreamInfo);
wmmeStreamInfo.hostApiType = paMME; 
wmmeStreamInfo.version = 1;
wmmeStreamInfo.flags = paWinMmeUseMultipleDevices;
wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels.channelCount = 2;
wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels.device = 3;
wmmeStreamInfo.devices = &wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels;
wmmeStreamInfo.deviceCount = 4;
outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = &wmmeStreamInfo;
```

The device id = 3 was obtained through

```
Pa_GetHostApiInfo( Pa_HostApiTypeIdToHostApiIndex( paMME ) )->defaultOutputDevice
```

I hope I have made the query clear enough. Will be happy to provide more details if required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the mistake :-)
The configuration for multiple devices must be made as an array. For instance, in the above case 
`wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels` must be an array of 4, with each individual *device* field containing the corresponding device index of each of the 4 stereo devices. The *channelCount* remains 2. The `outputParameters.channelCount` still has to be the aggregate number of channels, i.e. 8. With this I was able to run the application with a single stream, and of course, without any errors related to invalid device or invalid number of channels.:-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code pasted above, it looks like you are trying to call open on a single 8-channel device.  Instead you will have to get the Pa index of all four devices and call open 4 times.  Once for each stereo device.  You will then have 4 interleaved stereo streams to maintain.  My guess is that changing channelCount = 8 to channelCount = 2 will allow the first stream to open.

Comment: @trukvl.. Thanks for the reply. The system does work if I use a single device , i.e. if I set outputParameters.channelCount to 2(as you have mentioned) and deviceCount to 1. The only catch is,it'll be stereo output, which is of course expected. Now extending this to play 8-channel(by modifying the stereo configuration to be as given in the question) seems to be giving the problem.. I shall try out your suggestion about opening 4 streams and get back.