# Portaudio MME device behaviour issue

Tags: portaudio

I am using the multiple-output-device feature provided by paMME host API to output audio through multiple stereo devices. I also need to use a single multichannel input device using MME. 
- When I configure just the output device and play internally generated audio, there is no problem.
- However problem starts to occur when I configure both the input device and the mulitple-stereo output devices. The application crashes when I try to use more than two channels on the output. That is, if I try to increment the 'out' pointer for more than 2*frames_per_buffer , it crashes, which indicates that buffer has been allocated only to two output channels.

Can anybody throw some light on what could be the problem. The configuration code is given below:

```
    outputParameters.device = paUseHostApiSpecificDeviceSpecification;
    outputParameters.channelCount = 8;       
    outputParameters.sampleFormat = paInt16;
    outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    wmmeStreamInfo.size = sizeof(PaWinMmeStreamInfo);
    wmmeStreamInfo.hostApiType = paMME; 
    wmmeStreamInfo.version = 1;
    wmmeStreamInfo.flags = paWinMmeUseMultipleDevices;

    wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels[0].device = selectedDeviceIndex[0];
    wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels[0].channelCount = 2; 

    wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels[1].device = selectedDeviceIndex[1];
    wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels[1].channelCount = 2;

    wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels[2].device = selectedDeviceIndex[2];
    wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels[2].channelCount = 2;

    wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels[3].device = selectedDeviceIndex[3];
    wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels[3].channelCount = 2;

    wmmeStreamInfo.devices = wmmeDeviceAndNumChannels;
    wmmeStreamInfo.deviceCount = 4;

    outputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( selectedDeviceIndex[0] )->defaultLowOutputLatency;
    outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = &wmmeStreamInfo;

    inputParameters.device = selectedInputDeviceIndex; /* default output device */
    inputParameters.channelCount = 8;       /* stereo output */
    inputParameters.sampleFormat = paInt16; /* 32 bit floating point output */
    inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( inputParameters.device )->defaultLowInputLatency;
    inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;
```

Thanks and regards,

Siddharth Kumar.

Comment: A similar question was asked recently.  Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313162/configuring-multiple-devices-in-portaudio-invalid-device-error/19329409#19329409

Comment: Actually that was a question I had posted myself:-). The question above is a sequel to that. In short, I have got the multiple device configuration to work, but only when I use output alone. When I add an input MME device as well, it does not behave in the intended manner(Essentially, I am not able to get multiple channels support on the output side).